# Shallow CNN model Using python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras-layer

I have tried compiling the architectural model for convolution layers of a CNN model ...and i get this error when compiling the following code....Kindly help me in fixing this..

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(6, 5, 5, input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols), padding='same'))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(16, 5, 5, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(120, 5, 5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(84))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

when i compile the above snippet i get the following error..

> conv2d_args_preprocessor
>       'It seems that you are using the Keras 2 '
>
> ValueError: It seems that you are using the Keras 2 and you are passing both `kernel_size` and `strides` as integer positional arguments. For safety reasons, this is disallowed. Pass `strides` as a keyword argument instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the error statement says. Why not pass the strides value as a keyword argument.

```
model.add(Convolution2D(6, 5, strides=5, input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols), padding='same'))
```

Comment: An throws up after executing the above code....AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'